# jquery селектор по нескольким значениям атрибута

Tags: jquery

Привет.
Пытаюсь выбрать одним селектором несколько чекбоксов с указанным значением name и значением value из набора. Т.е. на странице есть 4 чекбокса с name = 'name' и value от 1 до 4, необходимо выбрать с name = 'name', value = 1 и value = 3. Все одним селектором. Это возможно?

Что-то вроде `$('input[type=checkbox][name=type][value=1,3]')`, но чтоб работало.

Спасибо.

Comment: $('input[type=checkbox][name=type][value=1],input[type=checkbox][name=type][value=3]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В некоторых случаях, достаточно удобно использовать метод [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). Вот, к примеру, нам нужно выбрать и отметить чекбоксы, значения которых собраны в массиве ([тестим в песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/7gdsppyL/)).

```
var needed = [2,3,6,7]; // value необходимых чекбоксов
$(':checkbox[name=type]').filter(function(){
    return needed.indexOf( +$(this).val() ) != -1;
}).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: А как можно найти элемент например с таким тегом и значением: name = d[270][774]

Comment: @Виталий, можно, только значение атрибута берите в кавычки. `$('[name="d[270][774]"]')`

Answer (score 0):

Если есть желание сделать "красиво" с помощью jQuery, то можете его "расширить" - см. http://habrahabr.ru/post/165197/

Рекомендую Вам действовать традиционным методом: получать все checkbox-ы с заданным name и их программно фильтровать.

Или же сформировать строку со всеми индивидуальными селекторами каждого чекбокса через запятую и сделать один запрос jQuery.

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=type][value=1], input[type=checkbox][name=type][valu‌​e=3]')
```

Comment: Запись можно немного сократить. 

:checkbox вместо input[type=checkbox]